# How to connect Hive served in dataproc cluster using pyhive

Tags: python, hive, connection, dataproc, pyhive

Could not connect to any of [('host', port)]
Hive Connection is not valid. Error: Could not connect to any of [('host', port)]

I'm trying to connect to hive which is hosted in dataproc cluster using pyhive and facing this error

```
from pyhive import hive
import pandas as pd

try:
        conn = hive.Connection(host=host, port=port)
        status = True
        print("Hive Connection is valid.")
except Exception as e:
        status = False
        print("Hive Connection is not valid. Error:", e)
```